# How Do I tether without root on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, tethering, emulation

Currently I use PDAnet for my windows machines, but after just installing Ubuntu 10.10 netbook remix on my hp mini I realized that PDAnet has no Ubuntu client. Is there any way to run PDAnet or its services in linux? Does linux have an alternative Android tethering client?

I tagged this as emulation because, being that this is a Ubuntu forum, I am looking for a solution based in the OS as Android doesn't seem to be helping me out. I am guessing that it might be something short of a VM solution, but this is a netbook and likely doesn't have the resources to run VirtualBox etc.

*Note: This is for a non-root, US Motorola Droid on Verizon with 2.2 (wifi disabled by carrier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `EasyTether`, it works for me (Samsung Spica & Motorola Milestone) - it has Ubuntu .deb package to install.

Answer (score 3):

On my Nexus One tethering works out of the box, when I put the phone in tether mode and plug it in network-manager detects it and it connects.

Comment: Your Nexus One has 2.2 Froyo, and almost all 2.2 have tethering available.

Comment: @pawel Even when I had 2.1 I could just tether my connection to my laptop on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pawel That's not true, in some places like the US you need 2.2 and some carriers actually block the functionality.

Comment: @Jorge I am looking for a Ubuntu based solution since mine is one of the handsets with that feature blocked. I am running a non-root moto Droid but wanted to keep this on topic to this site. (Yes I do have an AE.SE question up, but if I find an OS solution it might save me from needing two tethering apps; one each for windows and Linux. )

Comment: EasyTether works without root

Comment: @mfg Can you edit your question to add this information into your question? Thanks.

Comment: @jorge ; the reason this was not included in the question originally is that I didn't want this to be a question primarily about Android, but rather Ubuntu inter-operability